# Youtube 1080p working good, but 720p not (Ubuntu 13.10, Firefox)

Tags: 13.10, resolution, youtube

I have a weird problem with Youtube on Ubuntu 13.10(Firefox).

I can play a 1080p resolution video in fullscreen with good framerate (at any resolution: 480p, 720p...).

But when I want to play a video that has a max resolution of 720p making it fullscreen affects the framerate and it becomes laggy (this doesn't happen when not in fullscreen).

I have :

> Ubuntu 13.10, using Firefox.
>  CPU: Intel Core Quad Q8400
>   2,6hz,
>   GPU: Ati HD 5670.

Also the video controller bar on the bottom is bigger when the max video resolution is only 720p.

Any suggestion on how can I fix this?

Here are 2 pictures. First is a video that has max resolution 720p, second is a video that has max resolution 1080p:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier today. I removed flash player plug in using terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```

Now I don't have problems with controller bar, no mater witch resolution is set on full screen.